# Cannot cast from Properties to Hashtable

Tags: java, eclipse

I dont undrestand what is wrong here? any help?

```
    final char[] pass = "filePassW0rd3437 JPassW0rd3437".toCharArray();
    final Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty("user", "JoParak");
    ((Hashtable<String, char[]>)prop).put("password", pass);// I get Error
```

Thanks

Comment: **What is the error??** Please don't make us sit here and guess what it might be, just tell us. Did you look at any examples on how to use a Hashtable?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that strange cast there?

Comment: :) i got this "Cannot cast from Properties to Hashtable<String,char[]>"

Comment: Although `Properties` extends `Hashtable`, you probably don't want to abuse that. Better stay safe with `getProperty()` and `setProperty()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast to `Hashtable<String, char[]>`, only to `Hashtable<Object, Object>`.

When posting a question here, POST the copy-and-pasted error message.  Since the errors and other messages also identify lines by numbers, include the line number at least of the line(s) in questions.  Don't make us take up our time guessing what you're after, much less what has happened.

Comment: (sigh) take a step back.  Look at your problem  Try to phrase your question for knowledgeable, friendly people who have never seen your problem before.  To start with, you have to tell them what you want to do, and maybe what you've tried, and maybe what self-contained, executable code exhibits the behavior that you want explained.

Comment: Looking at the question again, I'm going to guess that you are trying to store your password as an array of characters because that's the format you want it in later, or because someone told you it was more secure that way?  If that's important, don't use a properties file, or cast the Object you stored to a char[] after you get it out; I'd see about storing it as a String, and converting (not casting) to a char[] later.